# What is language-conditioned visual reasoning?

Tags: computer-vision, terminology, papers, reasoning

Can anyone explain what language-conditioned visual reasoning is?
I saw this term in [this paper](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/CVPR2021/html/Yang_Bottom-Up_Shift_and_Reasoning_for_Referring_Image_Segmentation_CVPR_2021_paper.html) and I searched on the internet but I couldn't find a proper explanation.